# How can we calculate the limit $\lim_{x \to +\infty} e^{-ax} \int_0^x e^{at}b(t)dt$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

I am looking at the following exercise:

Let the (linear) differential equation $y'+ay=b(x)$ where $a>0, b$ continuous on $[0,+\infty)$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} b(x)=l \in \mathbb{R}$.

Show that each solution of the differential equation goes to $\frac{l}{a}$ while $x \to +\infty$,

i.e. if $\phi$ is any solution of the differential equation, show that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \phi(x)=\frac{l}{a}$.

That's what I have tried:

The solution of the differential equation will be of the form:

$\phi(x)=ce^{-ax}+e^{-ax} \int_0^x e^{at}b(t) dt$

$\lim_{x \to +\infty} c e^{-ax}=0$

So, $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \phi(x)=\lim_{x \to +\infty} e^{-ax} \int_0^x e^{at}b(t)dt$

How can we calculate the limit $\lim_{x \to +\infty} e^{-ax} \int_0^x e^{at}b(t)dt$ ?

**EDIT**: 
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} b(x)= l \in \mathbb{R}$$

That means that $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq n_0$: $|b(x)-l|< \epsilon \Rightarrow - \epsilon< b(x)-l< \epsilon \Rightarrow l- \epsilon<b(x)<l+ \epsilon$.

We pick $\epsilon=\frac{l}{2}$ and so we have that: $b(x)>\frac{l}{2}$.

Thus $\int_0^x e^{at} b(t)dt> \int_0^x e^{at} \frac{l}{2} dt=\frac{l}{2} \int_0^x e^{at}dt$

- If $l>0$ then $\frac{l}{2} \int_0^x e^{at}dt \to +\infty$ and so $\int_0^x e^{at} b(t)dt$ diverges.
- If $l<0$ then $\frac{l}{2} \int_0^x e^{at}dt \to -\infty$ and so $\int_0^x e^{at} b(t)dt$ diverges.

In both of the above cases, we can use the Fundamental Theorem Of Calculus:

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} e^{-ax} \int_0^x e^{at} b(t) dt= \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\int_0^x e^{at} b(t) dt}{e^{ax}}=\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{e^{ax} b(x)}{a e^{ax}} \to \frac{l}{a}$$

What can we say for the case $l=0$?

Comment: **Hint:** L'Hôpital.

Comment: @GitGud Can we use L'Hôpital since we know that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \int_0^x e^{at} b(t)dt=+\infty$? If so, how do we deduce it?

Comment: Are you asking why $\lim \limits_{x \to +\infty} \int_0^x e^{at} b(t)\,\mathrm dt=+\infty$? It's not necessarily true, it could also be $-\infty$ or $0$ depending on the sign of $l$. If, for instance, $l$ is negative, then, for big enough $t$, $b$ behaves as a (negative) constant, so you actually have $\text{constant}\cdot e^{at}$, now you can multiply inside and out by $-1$ just to get the signs right and you can apply L'Hôpital. This is the basic idea.

Comment: @GitGud Why do we consider  $t \to +\infty$ only for $b(t)$ to have $\text{constant} \cdot e^{at}$ ? If $t$ is big enough, doesn't $e^{at}$ go to $+\infty$ ?

Comment: Yes, you need to consider everything.

Comment: @GitGud Could you explain me further what I have to do? I am confused right now... :/

Comment: No proof, but some intuition that I don't find mentioned anywhere: 1) $y'(x)=b(x)-a y(x)$, so if $y(x)<b(x)/a$, then $y'(x)>0$ and $y$ is increasing. If $y(x)>b(x)/a$, then $y'(x)<0$ and $y$ is decreasing. So, we should not be surprised by the limit. 2) _If_ $y$ converges and is well-behaved, then it is reasonable to assume that $y'(x)\to 0$ as $x\to+\infty$. Looking at the equation, we must have the suggested limit.

Comment: @GitGud I have edited my post. Could you take a look at it?

Answer (score 3):

One idea is to break up $\int_0^x e^{at}b(t)dt$ into two parts,

$$\int_0^M e^{at}b(t) \ dt + \int_M^x e^{at}b(t) \ dt$$

where $M$ comes from the limit of $b$. Namely, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $M$ such that

$$x > M \ \Rightarrow |b(x) - L| < \epsilon$$

I.e., $x > M$ implies $L - \epsilon < b(x) < L + \epsilon$. This enables you to put upper and lower bounds on the second integral.

The first integral when multiplied by $e^{-ax}$ goes to zero.

---

Although I just saw Git Gud's hint to use L'Hôpital. That would be simplier ;-)

Comment: I have edited my post. Could you take a look at it?

Answer (score 2):

[L'Hôpital's rule](http://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=686) can be applied if it is only known that the limit of the denominator is $\infty$. Then

$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty} e^{-ax} \int_0^x e^{at}\,b(t)\,dt=\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{\int_0^x e^{at}b(t)dt}{e^{ax}}=\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{e^{ax}\,b(x)}{a\,e^{ax}}=\frac{l}{a}.
$$

Comment: Could you explain me why L'Hôpital's rule can be applied if it is only known that the limit of the denominator is $\infty$? I thought that we have to have a form like one of these: $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.. :/

Comment: Follow the link in my answer.

Comment: I have seen it.. But is this known? Because I didn't find it in Wikipedia.. :/

Comment: It is not included in most calculus tests, but it is well known.

Comment: I have edited my post. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: Looks fine, except at the end I think that you mean $l=0$, not $b=0$. In that case $|b(t)|\le\epsilon$ for $t$ large and $\Bigl|\int_0^xe^{at}b(t)\,dt\Bigr|\le\epsilon\int_0^xe^{at}\,dt$.

Comment: And then $ \epsilon \int_0^x e^{at} dt \to +\infty$. But from that we cannot deduce something for $\int_0^x e^{at} b(t) dt$, or can we? If not, how can we calculate in this case the limit?

Comment: For $x$ large enough $$\Bigl|e^{-ax} \int_0^x e^{at}\,b(t)\,dt\Bigr|\le\epsilon\,\frac{1-e^{-ax}}{a}\le\frac{\epsilon}{a}.$$